# What's the difference between public STATIC and public function in php?

Tags: php

I know there are a lot of information according to this, but I couldn't find any really useful and understandable. So what is the difference between `public static function` and `public function`? Why sometimes I have to use the word `static`?

I know that static functions are called by `::` and non-static by `->`, but the real difference (why sometimes I should use `static` I don't get). As I understand now, when I use `static`, I can call it from another class. Without it - I cannot. But I'm pretty sure that I'm wrong.

I think this information would be really helpful for a lot of ppl. Thanks for your time in trying to explain it.

Answer (score 12):

**Static** means that it can be accessed without instantiating a class.  This is good for constants.

**Static** methods need to have no effect on the state of the object.  They can have local variables in addition to the parameters.

Public: **Public** declared items can be accessed everywhere.

**Example:**

```
class test {
    public function sayHi($hi = "Hi") {
        $this->hi = $hi;
        return $this->hi;
    }
}
class test1 {
    public static function sayHi($hi) {
        $hi = "Hi";
        return $hi;
    }
}

//  Test
$mytest = new test();
print $mytest->sayHi('hello');  // returns 'hello'
print test1::sayHi('hello');    //  returns 'hello'
```

**More info:**

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: This will return "Hi" not "hello" 
print test1::sayHi('hello');    //  returns 'Hi'
.update it

Answer (score 4):

Keyword static in OOP approach describes functions/variables that are not instantiated with a new object, but are available without instantiation and are shared among all instances of an object. 
It can be handy to use, for a variable you can have a "counter" or "flag" shared among objects of the same class. 
Or if you are building an utils class library you might want a static singleton with static methods, so any code from a project can call it without the need for "new" call.

Answer (score 3):

First of all what is static?

> Static means that it can be accessed without instantiating a class.
>   This is good for constants.
>
> Static methods need to have no effect on the state of the object. They
>   can have local variables in addition to the parameters.

Now why you write public function

> The visibility of a property, a method or (as of PHP 7.1.0) a constant
>   can be defined by prefixing the declaration with the keywords public,
>   protected or private. Class members declared public can be accessed
>   everywhere. Members declared protected can be accessed only within the
>   class itself and by inheriting and parent classes. Members declared as
>   private may only be accessed by the class that defines the member.

Using public function example

```
class MyClass
{
    public $public = 'Public';
    protected $protected = 'Protected';
    private $private = 'Private';

    function printHello()
    {
        echo $this->public;
        echo $this->protected;
        echo $this->private;
    }
}

$obj = new MyClass();
```

Also Static example

```
<?php
class Foo {
    public static function aStaticMethod() {
        // ...
    }
}

Foo::aStaticMethod();
$classname = 'Foo';
$classname::aStaticMethod(); // As of PHP 5.3.0
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

The simple and visible difference between public static function and public function is  : Static function you can access without creating object.

Following code snippet give you more clarity :

```
class my_public {
    public function myfunc() {
        $val = "Hello I am public function"; 
        return $val;
    }
}
class my_static_public {
    public static function myfunc() {
        $val = "Hello I am public static function";
        return $val;
    }
}

// Access Test
$mytest = new my_public();
print $mytest->myfunc();  // returns 'Hello I am public function'
print my_static_public::myfunc(); //  returns 'Hello I am public static function'
```

More about static you [click here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php).

Answer (score 1):

The `public` keyword determines from *where* you can access the function, where:

- `public` allows access from everywhere
- `private` allows access only from within the class itself

The keyword `static` makes a function accessible **without the need of an instance of this class**. This means you can call `static` functions from any context, without the need to create an instance of the class, which you would have to do otherwise. Attention: As you don't have an object you can refer to when calling static methods, you **can not use the `this` keyword**.

Answer (score 0):

completely different types is exist in here:
(speed , imunity,accessibility,effectiv)
http://www.codedwell.com/post/59/static-vs-non-static-methods-in-php

Comment: Please add the relevant content to your answer and not simply link to another page.

Comment: ok sir i will do next time