# php static function class save previous function call data

Tags: php, class, oop, instance, static-functions

```
    class User
{
    private static $User;
    public static function get()
    {
        if (empty(self::$User)) {
            echo "Create New Object<br/>";
            return self::$User = new User();
        }
        echo "Already Created<br/>";
        return self::$User;
    }
}

User::get();
User::get();
User::get();
User::get();
```

This is my code. when I run this code then output given this code is,

```
Create New Object
Already Created
Already Created
Already Created
```

But why? My expected output is,

```
Create New Object
Create New Object
Create New Object
Create New Object
```

Because when we call a static function in class then it's full newly call this class and all time it creates a new object because all time the user is empty when calling this function. but why this code saves previous class data?

Comment: You need to understand what static means before you use it. This output is expected

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between public STATIC and public function in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45476515/whats-the-difference-between-public-static-and-public-function-in-php)

Comment: The output is more than just expected - saving state across calls is the *entire point* of a static class property. If you don't want that, then a static property is not the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your expected output is:

```
Create New Object
Create New Object
Create New Object
Create New Object
```

Then what you want is:

```
class User
{
    public function __construct() {
       echo "Create New Object<br/>";
    }
    public static function get()
    {
       return new self();
    }
}

$user1 = User::get();
$user2 = User::get();
$user3 = User::get();
$user4 = User::get();

// or

$user1 = new User();
$user2 = new User();
$user3 = new User();
$user4 = new User();
```

As people pointed out in the comments, the `static` flag indicates that there is only one instance of a variable across the entire class definition. If you want to create a new instance of the `User::$User` property, then there's no point in having it attached as a static variable to the class definition.