# Non-static method common\components\DirectoryHelpers::mimeType() should not be called statically

Tags: yii, yii2, php-5.6

totally php newbie here.
need help about our library program here.
i try to upload our book cover to our webserver, but get this error instead.
the problem lines here

[image: the error]

got this task to connecting our offline library sytem to webserver ( make it online )
this is what its looks like from the browser
[image: browser perspective]

Comment: method `mimeType()` is not declared using [static keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45476515/whats-the-difference-between-public-static-and-public-function-in-php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The following code:**

```
$mimetype=DirectoryHelpers::mimeType($files_uploaded);
```

**Change as follows:**

```
$var = new DirectoryHelpers();
$mimetype = $var->mimeType($files_uploaded);
```

**Or as a shorthand:**

```
$mimetype = (new DirectoryHelpers)->mimeType($files_uploaded);
```

In general: It depends on your needs. If you do not need to instantiate a class, you can change your library function to static. treat static functions like constants, (can not have objects)
**Example here:**

```
class DirectoryHelpers {
    public static function mimeType() {
        // code ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Change as follows:

$var = new DirectoryHelpers();
$mimetype = $var->mimeType($files_uploaded);

this works like a charm. can't thank you enough. have no idea how it works lol. 
still need learning a lot about php 

thank you sir